# DateTime format in Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am fetching datetime from SQL Server using Entity Framework. The format in my database is `2013-01-01 00:00:00.000` where as when I get it via Entity Framework in JSON format, it is `"\\/Date(1356980400000+0500)\\/"`.

Here is my code

```
public class SurveyData
{       
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; } 
}

var surveyDataList = (from survey in context.FDT_SURVEY                             
                      where survey.Name == surveyName 
                      select new SurveyData
                          {
                              SurveyID = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)survey.SURVEY_ID).Trim(),
                              CreatedDate = survey.CREATED_DATE,
                          }
    );
```

in my database, the datatype of `CREATED_DATE` is `datetime`.

Unable to understand what is the issue. Any help !

Comment: `DATETIME` in SQL Server is **not** stored in any string format - it's stored as an 8 byte datatype. SQL Server dates don't have any **format** associated with them by default. The date you're showing in JSON is the standard JSON encoding. So what's the problem with that??

Comment: \\/Date(1356980400000+0500)\\/ , I am receiving date time in this format.

Comment: Yes - again - what is the problem with that?? That is standard JSON - can you not convert it to a .NET object - or what's the problem??

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0,d}")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework doesn't return anything in JSON format. It populates .NET objects with data, or populates databases with data from .NET objects. Attaching the debugger would show that the `CreatedDate` has the correct value in it, I believe.

The actual problem is more likely to do with the fact that JSON has no concept of a "date" or "datetime" type, despite the comments on the question. See [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format). Some serialization code is taking the .NET `SurveyData` class and serializing it to JSON using the .NET framework's JSON serializer (possibly the `DataContractJsonSerializer`) and this is writing it out in the format you are seeing. This might be WCF or else an older version of ASP.NET MVC or Web API.

Later versions of ASP.NET use the [NewtonSoft JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library to perform serialization of objects. By default these use the ISO 8601 format, which is what most of the world expects in a JSON object for a date or datetime field.